# Speeding up Facebook graph API calls

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, batch-processing

I have an application that uses this [Python Facebook SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) to make a complex graph API call like this (basically, it takes care of the URL construction, etc.):

```
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends", limit="100", fields="name,link,gender,bio,education,relationship_status,music.limit(20).fields(name),movies.limit(20).fields(name),books.limit(20).fields(name),likes.limit(50).fields(name)")
```

This call is very slow for a user with more than a few friends. Is there an easy way to get this data more efficiently? Perhaps with other tools like the batching API?

Comment: You'll probably have to create your own Facebook wrapper which uses async calls to Facebook's API. Gevent with Python-Requests perhaps.